# Show URL with ID in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC so I am still learning my way. I am submitting a form,and I need to grab the data of one of the textboxes and pass it to the URL. My Routeconfig is default so I know I have the route correctly, now this is my controller:

```
    AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Verify(string verificationString)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

And my view has this:

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("Verify", "Status", FormMethod.Post)) {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.verificationCode, new { @name="verificationID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "18", @required="required" })
 }
```

I don't know how to pass this variable in the URL so it shows /Status/Verify/verificationstring(textbox data). How can I do this?

EDIT: RouteConfig

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

EDIT: FullView

```
  @model LSFVerif.Models.StatusModel
 <div class='form-group' style="text-align:center">

  @using(Html.BeginForm("Verify", "Status", FormMethod.Post)) {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @type="email", @placeholder = "Email", @maxlength = "100", @required="required" })


 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VerificationCode, new { @name="VerificationCode", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Codigo", @maxlength = "18", @required="required" })


          <button class='btn-lg btn-primary' type='submit'>Verify</button>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Verify", "Status", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.verificationCode, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "18", @required = "required" })
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
and 

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Verify(string verificationCode)
    {

          return RedirectToActionPermanent("Vierified", "Status", new
            {
                id = verificationCode
            });
    }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Vierified(string verificationCode)
        {
            return View("Vierified");
        }
```

Comment: Tried both methods and whenever I submit I get the same URL. Just Status/Verify and nothing afterwards. Will post routeconfig just in case.

Comment: Added the View. Submit button is there, and it is passing the value not just showing the URL as it should. Button is inside the form.

Comment: The value is not showing in the URL because it's a post action.  If you need to show use RedirectToActionPermanent - check the example i added.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your parameters to this:

```
AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Verify(ThisShouldBeTheNameOfYourModel model)
{

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, changed to this but no go. Still get the same URL.

Comment: Look at the view, the name of the model is at the top of the page it will start with @model use that name and replace ThisShouldBeTheNameOfYourModel with the name of the model.  Also make sure the name of the controller is StatusController.  You do not need @name="verificationID", you do need a submit button.

Comment: Yes, the model is the same. I also have the submit button, just didn't post it. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You have a break point @ the return View(); ?  Is the page refreshing?

Comment: Yes, in fact it IS passing the parameter as I am getting the input in the variable, its just not showing that data in the URL itself.